# Finding the non zero digit after mutiplying each element in array

Tags: c++

Input:
N = 4
arr = {3, 23, 30, 45}
Output:
5
Explanation:
Product of these numbers is 93150. Rightmost
non-zero digit is 5.

can u solve this question in c++ and run this code for input i give u.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoXPA.png)

```
// my code for this question
int rightmostNonZeroDigit(int N,arr[])
{
    // Write your code here.
    long int t = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        t = t * arr[i];
    }
    while (t > 0)
    {
        if ((t % 10) != 0)
        {
            return (t % 10);
        }
        t = t / 10;
    }
     return -1;
}
// what changes should i make in this code
```

Comment: my code run fine with input size smaller but get wrong for this large input size.

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mre].

Comment: you need to provide code. For large numbers you can have overflow. Use long long instead of int.

Comment: i already used long  long int  but that is not working as well

Comment: You could check if the last digit is 0 while calculating the product. Then the numbers won't get too big that fast

Comment: The input of one test case is probably too large to fit in any integer type. So you must be smarter about it then just adding all the numbers. Leetcode is often supposed to be a "challenge"

Comment: Could you also provide the input numbers as text and not as image. That way we can reproduce your problem wihtout manually typing all the numbers

Comment: you can strip off any trailing zeros from the numbers before the multiplication. Also you need only keep a single digit of the result of multiplication.

Comment: Multiplying 509 at least 3 digit numbers gives a resul of 10^(3*506). This is a number with 1500 digits! The solution cannot be found by multiplication. You need to check, when a "0" in a multiplication would appear . . . So this is a mathematical puzzle. Not about programming.

Answer (score 5):

This is actually a nice little challenge. You are multiplying (based from a short estimation on your input image) about 500 numbers with 3 digits each. The product of all these number will never fit into any standard integer type provided by C++.

Suppose your variable `t` holds some four digit number "abcd". You can write it like

```
t = a * 1000 + b * 100 + c * 10 + d
```

Now if you multiply `t` with any other number `x` you get

```
t * x = a * x * 1000 + b * x * 100 + c * x * 10 + d * x
```

As you can see the last digit of `t*x` is **only** determined by `d*x`. All the other components have trailing zeros since they are some multiple of a power of ten. That means to get the last digit of any multiplication, you just have to multiply the two last digits of the numbers.

Now you are not interested in the last digit, but in the last non-zero digit. You will get the right result if you only ever keep the last non-zero digit in `t` while calculating the product of all the numbers. In your code you could do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    t = t * arr[i];

    // the following will remove all trailing zeros
    while ( t != 0 && t % 10 == 0 ) {
        t = t / 10;
    }
   
    // the following will remove all but the last digit
    t = t % 10;
}
```

This works because trailing zeros in the intermediate result will never influence anything but the number of trailing zeros in the final result. And digits before the last non-zero digit will also never contribute to the last non-zero digit in the final result.

**Addition**
On [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Tsa8vG457) you can find a live example with your test input `arr = {3,23,30,45}`.

**Important Edit**
As @MohammedfaizKhan pointed out there are cases where the above code fails. For example if we take the numbers `arr = {15,2}`. The code from above yields `1` because it truncates the `1` in `15` before multiplying it with `2`. If we call `D` the operation that tuncates a number to the first non zero digit, the above program could be written like:

|  | code from above produces |
| --- | --- |
| step one | `t = D(1 * 15) = 5` |
| step two | `t = D(5 * 2 ) = 1` |

The correct result would be `3`. Apparently we cannot remove all leading digits. We could try to increase the number of leading nonzero digits that are kept in each step. For example in the code above, we could use `t = t % 100` instead of `t = t % 10`. There is however a counter example for each number of digits we are trying to keep:

The numbers `2^n` and `5^n` don't have trailing zeros because they are no multiple of ten because a multiple of `10` must have `2` and `5` in its prime factorization. Their product `2^n * 5^n = (2*5)^n = 10^n` however has exactly `n` trailing zeros.

In conclusion we should keep as many leading nonzero digits as we can fit into our data type. For an 64bit unsigned int this would be for example `19` digits. However we also must not overflow while doing the multiplication with the array elements. Because your array elements are all no longer than 3 digits, we should be safe if we keep the leading 15 digits or something like that.

So in conclusion the following program should do the correct thing:

```
unsigned long long int t = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    t = t * arr[i];

    // the following will remove all trailing zeros
    while ( t != 0 && t % 10 == 0 ) {
        t = t / 10;
    }
   
    // the following will remove all but the last 15 digits
    t = t % 1000000000000000;
}
```

Comment: Well explained (have an upvote),. but you do need to consider the case when one of the inputs in the array is zero. As I do (apologies for plugging my answer).

Comment: @Bathsheba actually a good point, thanks for the hint. I will fix it.

Comment: not working for this test case. n=5 arr={7,6,6,5,1}

Comment: @MohammedfaizKhan you are absolutely right. I have to think about that one. For the meantime you could remove the `t = t % 10` line. But then you may get an overflow again in special cases.

Comment: @MohammedfaizKhan I added an update with a version that should work now.

Comment: @JakobStark I actually found a good solution on internet which i can share with but how can i share the code i am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: @MohammedfaizKhan just post a new answer to your own question. There you can include a multiline codeblock by enclosing it in triple backticks. Like \`\`\`<code>```

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to retain only the final non-zero digit on each step.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int arr[] = {3, 23, 30, 45};
    int n = 1;
    for (auto&& i : arr){
        if (!(n *= i)) break; // Zero in input needs special treatment
        for (; !(n % 10); n /= 10); // Remove trailing zeros
        n %= 10; // Retain single digit
    }
    std::cout << n;
}
```

is one way.

Comment: brother your code doesn't work for the given test case. N=5 arr=[7,6,6,5,1]    expexted output=6   our output=1